# Conditionally Apply an Interceptor in Spring

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

How can I conditionally add myOtherInterceptor below?

```
<bean id="myService" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.ProxyFactoryBean">
   <property name="proxyInterfaces"><value>IMyService</value></property>
   <property name="target">
      <bean parent="baseServiceTarget" class="MyService" />
   </property>
   <property name="interceptorNames">
      <list>
         <value>myInterceptor</value>
         <value>myOtherInterceptor</value>
      </list>
   </property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can have the condition within the interceptor.